# What is the statement like lambda definition in the first line after class definition in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the meaning of `a=>` in the below code? is it a pointer like `this` to the instantiated object?

```
class A {
  a=>
  def methodB()={
     .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a self reference or self type. In your case it means "create a symbol of name 'a' and point it to the this reference".

See the [SO Scala tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) in section "Self references" (chapter 17) for more information:

> 1. Self references
>
>    - [Unify types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932701/scala-two-methods-different-parameter-types-but-same-code-how-to-unify)
>    - [Self reference naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017357/difference-between-this-and-self-in-self-type-annotations)
>    - [Multiple self references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355060/are-multiple-self-types-possible)
>    - [Difference between self references and subtyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)